# Parcelable encountered IOException writing enum contained methods

Tags: java, android, serializable

There is a enum:

```
public static enum CheckResult {
    NONEEDTOUPDATE, 
    FORCEUPDATE, 
    OPTIONALUPDATE;

    public boolean hasNewVersion() {
        return this != NONEEDTOUPDATE;
    } 
}
```

and put it into another class:

```
public static class UpdateData implements Serializable {
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY = "UpdateData";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7956542923164822779L;
    public String apkDownloadUrl;
    public String newVersionName;
    public CheckResult checkResult;
}
```

and send it use bundle:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(UpdateData.BUNDLE_KEY, data);//data is an UpdateData instance
intent.putExtras(bundle);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

It will cause Exception.

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.tencent.game3366.update.UpdateChecker$UpdateData)
android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1323)
android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271)
android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7410)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2297)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1437)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3516)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3477)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3719)
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3687)
```

If I just change enum into :

```
public static enum CheckResult {
    NONEEDTOUPDATE, 
    FORCEUPDATE, 
    OPTIONALUPDATE 
}
```

Everything all right, why this happen?

**UPDATE**

When I rebuild whole project , no exception occur............What should I say......

Comment: Please give a reproducible example with the corresponding stack trace.

Comment: Works for me and I can compile your enum if I remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: Can you show us where you declare and initialize `data`? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @zzy What version of android are you using? I'm using 4.4 and I don't get any exception with either version of CheckResult. What you describe is really weird. It must surely be a bug.

Comment: Probably relates to this Lollipop issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80880

Comment: @pbabcdefp I'm using latest 4.4W and compile it by IntelliJ IDEA. And last time I test this code is using eclipse(ant) . Does it matters?

Comment: I don't know what matters here. I just know I don't get an exception. To get an answer to this I think you should improve the title. Something like: Why does Parcelable encounter IOException when I add method to Enum?

Comment: @pbabcdefp I found I can't get the exception if I put code in a brand new project , I will struggle to get what cause it

Answer (score -1):

Java enum, unlike C++, isn't integer based value. It's essentially a class with each enum "value" as a singleton instance of this class. Thus rather than comparing the underlying integer values as C++ does, it's really comparing the object identity equality when you do something like

`A.VALUE_A == A.VALUE_B`

When you do enum comparsion. Moreover, such enum class instances are constructed at initialization stage, meaning you would always have the instances available.

Now if enum is serializable, which implies it can be de-seraialized from streams, you are subject to the typical serialized singleton problem. Once you de-serialize an enum instance into the main memory, you would have 2 copies of such instance inside memory and the above comparison and all your other enum-ready structures, like `EnumMap` etc, doesn't hold any more based on instance equality ( == ) and system `hashCode()` (which is essentially System.identityHashCode() for default implementation if you are using SUN/Oracle JVM).

The above problem is to be avoid at the language level - that's why you cannot declare an `Enum` to implement `Serializable`.

Comment: All Enums do implement Serializable. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Enum.html

Comment: I must admit I didn't know that either. My initial comment under this question (now deleted) was basically your answer.

Comment: I doubt it unless someone could point out how the above problem is solved by JVM.

Comment: If you want to know that, then create a new question for it, but it doesn't solve OPs problem.